# Change all values below a row using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I am working on df which represents US regions and contains states in it as well. The states have [edit] next to them. All regions between 2 states belong to the state above. I thought this should work, but it is not changing the values of the df for some reason... any idea what is happening here? and how would you do it?

Here is the df

```
0                      Alabama[edit]
1                            Auburn 
2                          Florence 
3                      Jacksonville 
4                        Livingston 
5                        Montevallo 
6                              Troy 
7                        Tuscaloosa 
8                          Tuskegee 
9                       Alaska[edit]
10                        Fairbanks 
11                     Arizona[edit]
12                        Flagstaff 
13                            Tempe 
14                           Tucson 
15                    Arkansas[edit]
16                      Arkadelphia 
17                           Conway 
18                     Fayetteville 
19                        Jonesboro 
20                         Magnolia 
21                       Monticello 
22                     Russellville 
23                           Searcy 
24                  California[edit]
25                           Angwin 
26                           Arcata 
27                         Berkeley 
28                            Chico 
29                        Claremont
```

And here is my solution that is not changing the df:

```
df['state'] = 'replace this'
edit = '\[edit\]'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if edit in row['RegionName']:
        st = df.loc[index, ['RegionName']]
        df.loc[index, ['RegionName']] = None
        df.iloc[index:, 1] = st
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace each region name with the name of its state?

Comment: the output should be 2 columns, each region with its state next to it,

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your column name is `regions`, you may use `str.extract`:

```
df.assign(
    state=df.region.str.extract(r'(.*?)\[edit\]').ffill()
).mask(df.region.str.endswith('[edit]')).dropna()

          region       state
1         Auburn     Alabama
2       Florence     Alabama
3   Jacksonville     Alabama
4     Livingston     Alabama
5     Montevallo     Alabama
6           Troy     Alabama
7     Tuscaloosa     Alabama
8       Tuskegee     Alabama
10     Fairbanks      Alaska
12     Flagstaff     Arizona
13         Tempe     Arizona
14        Tucson     Arizona
16   Arkadelphia    Arkansas
17        Conway    Arkansas
18  Fayetteville    Arkansas
19     Jonesboro    Arkansas
20      Magnolia    Arkansas
21    Monticello    Arkansas
22  Russellville    Arkansas
23        Searcy    Arkansas
25        Angwin  California
26        Arcata  California
27      Berkeley  California
28         Chico  California
29     Claremont  California
```

If you'd like to *keep* the states in your region column, just remove the `mask`:

```
df.assign(
    state=df.region.str.extract(r'(.*?)\[edit\]').ffill()
)
```

Comment: So ffill() replaces all the variables below automatically, right? Also, any idea why my values were not changing? in the original question

Comment: It replaced `NaN` with the last valid value before it, correct

Comment: Thank you very much. What am I missing with my iterrows method?

Comment: @Rami.K not entirely sure, I think you should use the row variable instead of using `loc` with the index, since you are already iterating through it.  However, this method should be faster than just iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here is a solution that avoids explicit looping.

```
# Create a new column of state names with NaN in any
# row that did not contain a state name flagged with "edit"
df['state'] = df[df['RegionName'].str.contains('edit')]['RegionName']

# Forward-fill the NaNs in the state column
df = df.ffill()

# Delete rows where RegionName == state and
# reset index to default integers
df = df[df.iloc[:, 0] != df.iloc[:, 1]].reset_index(drop=True)

# Delete "[edit]" flag from strings
df['state'] = df['state'].str.replace('\[edit\]', '')

# Result:
df
      RegionName       state
0         Auburn     Alabama
1       Florence     Alabama
2   Jacksonville     Alabama
3     Livingston     Alabama
4     Montevallo     Alabama
5           Troy     Alabama
6     Tuscaloosa     Alabama
7       Tuskegee     Alabama
8      Fairbanks      Alaska
9      Flagstaff     Arizona
10         Tempe     Arizona
11        Tucson     Arizona
12   Arkadelphia    Arkansas
13        Conway    Arkansas
14  Fayetteville    Arkansas
15     Jonesboro    Arkansas
16      Magnolia    Arkansas
17    Monticello    Arkansas
18  Russellville    Arkansas
19        Searcy    Arkansas
20        Angwin  California
21        Arcata  California
22      Berkeley  California
23         Chico  California
24     Claremont  California
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['State']=df['RegionName']
df.loc[~df['RegionName'].str.contains('[edit]'),'State']=np.nan
df['State']=df['State'].str.replace('[edit]','').fillna(method='ffill')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a mask which identifies the states. use that to create a new column for states, forward fill, and select only rows excluded by the mask.

```
mask = df.region.str.endswith('[edit]')
df.loc[mask, 'state'] = df.region[mask].str.replace('\[edit\]', '')
df.state = df.state.ffill()
df[~mask]
# outputs:
          region       state
1         Auburn     Alabama
2       Florence     Alabama
3   Jacksonville     Alabama
4     Livingston     Alabama
5     Montevallo     Alabama
6           Troy     Alabama
7     Tuscaloosa     Alabama
8       Tuskegee     Alabama
10     Fairbanks      Alaska
12     Flagstaff     Arizona
13         Tempe     Arizona
14        Tucson     Arizona
16   Arkadelphia    Arkansas
17        Conway    Arkansas
18  Fayetteville    Arkansas
19     Jonesboro    Arkansas
20      Magnolia    Arkansas
21    Monticello    Arkansas
22  Russellville    Arkansas
23        Searcy    Arkansas
25        Angwin  California
26        Arcata  California
27      Berkeley  California
28         Chico  California
29     Claremont  California
```